# Saving and Restoring a model using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, python-2.x

I saved parameters of my neural network using this:

```
parameters = {
    'w_h1': w_h1,
    'b_h1': b_h1,
    'w_h2':  w_h2,
    'b_h2': b_h2,
    'w_h3': w_h3,
    'b_h3': b_h3,
    'w_o':  w_o,
    'b_o':  b_o
} 

saver = tf.train.Saver(parameters)

saver.save(sess, 'my-model', global_step=epoch)
```

Now I have these 3 files in my disk:

```
checkpoint

my-model-114000

my-model-114000.meta
```

I tried something like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my-model-114000.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, 'my-model-114000')
```

I received the message:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from my-model-114000
```

However, I am not able to restore the original parameters. I tried something like this (inside the with tf.Session() as sess)

w_h1 = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("w_h1:0")

but I receive the message

```
KeyError: "The name 'w_h1:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'w_h1', does not exist in the graph."
```

However, I am not able to recover the weights. How can I do that?

I used

```
    for var in tf.all_variables():
        print str(var)
```

to know what had been saved and I realized that it saved a lot of stuff (just a sample below), but I though that I have saved only a small number of important parameters:

```
<tf.Variable 'Variable_21/Adam_3:0' shape=(50,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'Variable_24/Adam_2:0' shape=(50, 50) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'Variable_24/Adam_3:0' shape=(50, 50) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'Variable_25/Adam_2:0' shape=(50,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'Variable_25/Adam_3:0' shape=(50,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'Variable_28/Adam_2:0' shape=(50, 1) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'Variable_28/Adam_3:0' shape=(50, 1) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'Variable_29/Adam_2:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'Variable_29/Adam_3:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>
>>>
```

Comment: Make sure initialize the `tensorflow` graph by the same graph architecture as you did during saving.

Comment: @Ultraviolet: How can I do that?

Comment: Furthermore, even if I define the parameters to be saved tensorflow saves all variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

names like `'Variable_21/Adam_3:0'` is your variable names and `"w_h1"` isn't, you should get this tensor with `w_h1 = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("Variable_21/Adam_3:0")`

Comment: It is probably w_h1,w_h2 or w_h3. However, How can I know which one? I thought I was supposed to recover the variable by the name "w_h1:0".

Comment: you can name your variable with anything you want when creating it like `tf.Variable(name="w_h1")`.

Comment: The problem to recover the weights was that I was not naming the variables. Now I do that!